# Limit WP excerpt to second sentence

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this function to limit my WP excerpt to a sentence instead of just cutting it off after a number of words.

```
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'end_with_sentence');

function end_with_sentence($excerpt) {
  $allowed_end = array('.', '!', '?', '...');
  $exc = explode( ' ', $excerpt );
  $found = false;
  $last = '';
  while ( ! $found && ! empty($exc) ) { 
    $last = array_pop($exc);
    $end = strrev( $last );
    $found = in_array( $end{0}, $allowed_end );
  }
  return (! empty($exc)) ? $excerpt : rtrim(implode(' ', $exc) . ' ' .$last);
}
```

Works like a charm, but I would like to limit this to two sentences. Anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: What happens if a sentence contains something like `Mr.` or `Mrs.` or `Dr.`, `A.M.` or `P.M.` or `etc.`?

Comment: Well, it's a Dutch blog, so we don't use abbreviations like Mr. with a dot. And anyway, it's a rule in Dutch (well, they told me this at school and I still apply this to my texts) to write the full word instead of the abbreviations. So that's not really an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code didn't work for me for 1 sentence, but hey it's 2am here maybe I missed something. I wrote this from scratch:

```
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'end_with_sentence');

function end_with_sentence( $excerpt ) {
  $allowed_ends = array('.', '!', '?', '...');
  $number_sentences = 2;
  $excerpt_chunk = $excerpt;

  for($i = 0; $i < $number_sentences; $i++){
      $lowest_sentence_end[$i] = 100000000000000000;
      foreach( $allowed_ends as $allowed_end)
      {
        $sentence_end = strpos( $excerpt_chunk, $allowed_end);
        if($sentence_end !== false && $sentence_end < $lowest_sentence_end[$i]){
            $lowest_sentence_end[$i] = $sentence_end + strlen( $allowed_end );
        }
        $sentence_end = false;
      }

      $sentences[$i] = substr( $excerpt_chunk, 0, $lowest_sentence_end[$i]);
      $excerpt_chunk = substr( $excerpt_chunk, $lowest_sentence_end[$i]);
  }

  return implode('', $sentences);
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Is there also a possibility to add a Read more tag at the end?

Comment: I guess so, you could just replace `return implode('', $sentences);` with `return implode('', $sentences) . ' ... Read More';`. Depends how advanced you want your implementation to be.

Comment: @James Jones Clever!! Should be core!

Answer (score 1):

I see complexities in your sample code that make it (maybe) harder than it needs to be.

Regular expressions are awesome.  If you want to modify this one, I'd recommend using this tool: https://regex101.com/

Here we're going to use [preg_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

```
function end_with_sentence( $excerpt, $number = 2 ) {
    $sentences = preg_split( "/(\.|\!|\?|\...)/", $excerpt, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

    var_dump($sentences);

    if (count($sentences) < $number) {
         return $excerpt;
    }

    return implode('', array_slice($sentences, 0, ($number * 2)));
}
```

### Usage

```
$excerpt = 'Sentence. Sentence!  Sentence? Sentence';

echo end_with_sentence($excerpt); // "Sentence. Sentence!"
echo end_with_sentence($excerpt, 1); // "Sentence."
echo end_with_sentence($excerpt, 3); // "Sentence. Sentence!  Sentence?"
echo end_with_sentence($excerpt, 4); // "Sentence. Sentence!  Sentence? Sentence"
echo end_with_sentence($excerpt, 10); // "Sentence. Sentence!  Sentence? Sentence"
```